# How to pass variables on long press on ListView?

Tags: android, listview, variables, contextmenu

I would have listview and a lot of items inside. I want that user can long press on item and set it as Favorite. To do that, I need to get DB id to this menu on long press.

I have the following code

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, 
                              View v, 
                              ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

menu.setHeaderTitle("Favorite");
menu.add(0, REMOVE_TODO, Menu.NONE, R.string.favorit_add);
}
```

It works just fine... But what I want to do is to get text and database id of selected item.

So insetead of "Favorite" I would like to write Favorite: Item1.

If anyoune could help I would be thankful.

Here is a code for my adapter... I actually used example's adapter.

```
    package com.TVSpored;

import android.content.Context;
import java.util.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class ToDoItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ToDoItem> {

  int resource;

  public ToDoItemAdapter(Context _context, 
                             int _resource, 
                             List<ToDoItem> _items) {
    super(_context, _resource, _items);
    resource = _resource;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LinearLayout todoView;

    ToDoItem item = getItem(position);

    String taskString = item.getTask();
    String icon_name = item.getCreated();
    int fav = item.getFavorite();

    if (convertView == null) {
      todoView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
      String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
      LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(inflater); 
      vi.inflate(resource, todoView, true);
    } else {
      todoView = (LinearLayout) convertView;
    }

    ImageView favView = (ImageView)todoView.findViewById(R.id.rowImgFav);
    ImageView channelView = (ImageView)todoView.findViewById(R.id.rowImg);
    TextView channelName = (TextView)todoView.findViewById(R.id.row);

    //dateView.setText(dateString);

    channelView.setImageResource(getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("com.TVSpored:drawable/channels_"+icon_name , null, null));

    channelName.setText(taskString);

    if(fav == 0)
    {
        favView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sys_srcek_disabled);
    }
    else
    {
        favView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sys_srcek);
    }
    return todoView;
  }
  }
```

And furtherer my Item

```
package com.TVSpored;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class ToDoItem {

  String task;
  String created;
  Integer fav;
  Integer id;

  public String getTask() {
    return task;
  }

  public String getCreated() {
    return created;    
  }

  public Integer getFavorite()
  {
      return fav;
  }

  public Integer getID()
  {
      return id;
  }

  public ToDoItem(String _task, String _created, int _fav, int _id) {
    task = _task;
    created = _created;
    fav = _fav;
    id = _id;
  }

  }
```

Here is a code in main activity class

```
 @Override
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, 
                              View v, 
                              ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
 super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);


 menu.setHeaderTitle("Urejanje kanala");
 menu.add(0, REMOVE_TODO, Menu.NONE, R.string.favorit_add); 
 // static final private int REMOVE_TODO = Menu.FIRST + 1; // defined ad the begining
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

 AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
 int arrayAdapterPosition = menuInfo.position;

 ToDoItem todoItem = (ToDoItem)aa.getItem(arrayAdapterPosition);
 String task = todoItem.getTask();
 int id = todoItem.getID();

 int index = myListView.getSelectedItemPosition();
 aa.getItemId(index);

 changeFavorite(id);
 return true;
 }
```

Here is updateArray function (called on change)

```
private void updateArray() {
  toDoListCursor.requery();

  todoItems.clear();
  int j = 0;
  if (toDoListCursor.moveToFirst())
    do 
    { 
      String task =            toDoListCursor.getString(toDoListCursor.getColumnIndex(ToDoDBAdapter.KEY_NAME));
      String created = toDoListCursor.getString(toDoListCursor.getColumnIndex(ToDoDBAdapter.KEY_EPG_NAME));
      int fav = toDoListCursor.getInt(toDoListCursor.getColumnIndex(ToDoDBAdapter.KEY_EPG_NAME));
      int id = toDoListCursor.getInt(toDoListCursor.getColumnIndex(ToDoDBAdapter.KEY_ID));

      ToDoItem newItem = new ToDoItem(task, created, fav, id);
      todoItems.add(0, newItem);
      j++;
    } 
    while(toDoListCursor.moveToNext());

  aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and a populate function...

```
private void populateTChannels() {
// Get all the todo list items from the database.
toDoListCursor = toDoDBAdapter. getAllToDoItemsCursor();
if((toDoListCursor.getCount() == 0) || !toDoListCursor.moveToFirst())
{
    toDoDBAdapter.populateDB();
}

if(toDoDBAdapter.ChannelsArray.length > toDoListCursor.getCount())
{
    toDoDBAdapter.populateDBWhitCheck();
}
toDoListCursor = toDoDBAdapter. getAllToDoItemsCursor();
startManagingCursor(toDoListCursor);

// Update the array.
updateArray();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo` you get passed contains information about which item in the list was clicked. You can probably use this to get the information you need.

**Update:**

Somewhat like dziobas mentions in his answer you can do something like this to get to know which position the selected item has in your adapter:

```
AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
long arrayAdapterPosition = menuInfo.position;
```

Now you know the position, and can fetch it from your `ArrayAdapter`. If you have this `ArrayAdapter` instance stored in a member variable (in this example I have named it myArrayAdapter), you can then proceed to get the item with `ArrayAdapter.getItem(int position)`:

```
ToDoItem todoItem = (ToDoItem)myArrayAdapter.getItem(arrayAdapterPosition);
String task = todoItem.getTask();
int id = todoItem.getId();
```

You could now proceed to set the menu header title as follows:

```
menu.setHeaderTitle("Favorite: " + task + Integer.toString(id));
```

Comment: As seen above,  ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo. Yes my listview is populated using custom ArrayAdapter. Currently it is only populated by icon and name.
Would be grateful if you could tell me how to get let's say name out of it. 

Thanks. In case u need any additional data I will provide it.

Comment: Updated the answer. If you still don't quite understand how to put this together, I think we need to see more of your source code to be able to make a useful example. Definition of your array adapter, the definition of the items you put into it, the relevant parts of your activity where they are being used etc.

Comment: Hi, I have update question (main question) with a code of my item and my item adapter. As far as I understood, I have to make in my item's class a function to store position in listview and id? Is that correct? 

What is the best solution to do so?

Comment: You don't seem to need anything more inside your item. You get the items array adapter position from menuInfo (as shown), then you proceed to use `ArrayAdapter.getItem()` to retrieve the actual item from the adapter.

Comment: Oh, and I updated the examples slightly, according to your new information.

Comment: I have tried familiar before (Tried this one as well) and I always get id 2 (REMOVE_TODO variable)... I can't find the solution... I have updated question with all crucial data...

Comment: I don't quite understand. Where are you always getting 2? From todoItem.getId()? What about the REMOVE_TODO variable?

Comment: Heh.. found a mistake corrected it and now it works - I get the proper position (which is cool) :) But my question now is how to get DB ID from position?

Comment: If I'm not misunderstanding you, this is what is done in the second part of my example. You 1) use the position to retrieve your task from your arrayadapter, and 2) Since your task seems to already contain your DB id, you can just call `getId()` on the task?

Comment: Great! Missed that one sorry! I got like totally confused! Thanks for taking me out! :)

Comment: Hehe, I know the feeling. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If your adapter supports getting Id, so it should look like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    long id = menuInfo.id;
    ...
```