# Delete selected listview file from onContextItemSelected (Android)

Tags: android, android-listview, hashmap, listadapter

My activity implements listview for playing Items, on longClick of selected item is created oncontext menu which inflates floating delete "button" on click of that button the selected item should be deleted. The problem is that I don't know how to get the selected file name.

This is mainActivity :

```
    public class List2 extends ListActivity {
                ListView lv;
                ListAdapter adapter;
                String selection;


 public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.list2);
                        SongsManager plm = new SongsManager();
            // get all songs from sdcard
            this.songsList = plm.getPlayList();

            // looping through playlist
            for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(i);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                songsListData.add(song);
            }

            // Adding menuItems to ListView
             adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, songsListData,
           R.layout.playlist_item, new String[] { "songTitle" }, new int[] {
                            R.id.songTitle });



//         lv.invalidateViews();
            setListAdapter(adapter);
                    // selecting single ListView item
                  lv = getListView();

                 registerForContextMenu(getListView());


                    // listening to single listitem click
                    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                               final int position, long id) {
                            // getting listitem index
                       final  int songIndex = position;



    //                          // Starting new intent
                          Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                               AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.class);
                            // Sending songIndex to PlayerActivity
                            in.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);

                            startActivity(in);
                        }
                    });

                  }





 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
                MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
             }

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item,View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) { 
 AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                    int songPos = info.position;

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {


                case R.id.delete:

        HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(info.position);


       final String SD_PATH = new String("/storage/extSdCard/MUSIC/song.mp3");

                    File file = new File (SD_PATH );
                    if (file.exists())
                    {

                    file.delete(); 

                    }  


                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
                }
             }



        }
```

and this Class from which is getting the method getPlayList();

```
public class SongsManager {
    // SDCard Path
    final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/storage/emulated/0/Music");


    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

        if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
                HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
                song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
                song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

                // Adding each song to SongList
                songsList.add(song);
            }
        }
        // return songs list array
        return songsList;
    }

    /**
     * Class to filter files which are having .mp3 extension
     * */
    class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.endsWith(".mp3") || name.endsWith(".MP3"));
        }
    }

}
```

The final question is how to delete selected listview file permanently(from selected path) inside oncontextitemselected?

Comment: this must be so difficult noone answered. I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265303/android-delete-file-using-context-menu but wasn't a full answer,not so clear about how to delete the file

Comment: Using the selected index you can find the name of selected item.